# Structured Streaming - Running different function by key for message in the same batch

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have implemented a Kafka consumer in PySpark (Spark 2.2.1)

I'm using the structured-streaming technology.

Each receiving batch contains messages where the value column is from different types (distinguish by the key), and its schema is different.

Now, I want to run different logic on the value column according to the message column key.

How can I group (by key) the received messages, and run specific logic for each group in PySpark?

Here is a snippet from my code, which works when all messages are of the same type:

```py
lines = spark.readStream.format("kafka")...

schema_struct = get_schema_struct(...)

udf_identical_func = udf(
    lambda k,msg: do_something_identical_to_all_types(k,msg)), schema_struct
)

res = lines.select(udf_identical_func("key","value"))

udf_specific_toEach_type_func = udf(
    lambda k,msg: do_something_specific_to_each_type(k,msg)), schema_struct
)

res= res.select(udf_specific_toEach_type_func)
q = res.writeStream....
q.awaitTermination()
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Write an if statement inside the `udf(lambda k`?

Comment: "and its schema is different" -  in what way. Is the output different type for each key?

Comment: @user96 A ternary could work ;) But, more specifically, add to those `do_something` functions

Comment: @user96 the struct is different for each key (also different types in the struct)

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks. Do you mean to replace the schema_struct part in the UDF with if statement?

Comment: No. I'm saying replace the lambda with an actual function where you can use regular conditionals